# Reverse Array in java

Tags: java

```
//Revrse an array
import java.util.*;
public class ReverseSecond
{
    static int revArray(int []d)
    {
        int temp=0;

        for(int i=0;i<d.length/2;i++)
        {
            temp=d[i];
            d[i]=d[d.length-1-i];
            d[d.length-1-i]=temp;
        }
        return d;
    }
    public static void main(String h[]) 
    {
        int no[]={10,20,30,40,50};
        System.out.println("Before Reverse:-");

        for(int i=0;i<no.length;i++)
        {   
            System.out.println(""+no[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse Array is :-"+revArray(no));
    }
}
```

what will be the solution for this return type instead of this whether the error is showing in my command prompt is Incompatible type error int[] to int

Comment: Look at `int revArray(int []d)` and `return d;`. See the error? What did you declare to be the return type and what are you actually returning?

Comment: your revArray signature sais it will return a single int. but you need to return an int array.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an `int` rather than `int[]`

Change:

`static int revArray(int[] d)`

To:

`static int[] revArray(int[] d)`

Also if you want to print out the reversed array change:

`System.out.println("Reverse Array is :-" + revArray(no));`

To:

`System.out.println("Reverse Array is :-" + Arrays.toString(revArray(no)));`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not a direct solution to your problem. You might concider using `Collection` instead of arrays in Java. I personally think this would be much more clean code.

You can use some Java magic and reverse a collection like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> no = new ArrayList<Integer>(){};
        no.add(10);
        no.add(20);
        no.add(30);
        no.add(40);
        no.add(50);

        System.out.println("Before Reverse: " + no);

        Collections.reverse(no);

        System.out.println("After Reverse: " + no);

    }
```

**Ouput:**

```
Before Reverse: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
After Reverse: [50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
```